# I am getting ERROR. After publishing Site.com

Tags: site.com

I have created a site.com and in the site I have added some fields from my custom object to get display on the site.com. In the preview it is working fine but after i publish the site.com i am not able to view the records i am getting an error.

> Error 
>   We're unable to retrieve your data due to an error.

Please guide me what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if your are accessing your published page as an authenticated or unauthenticated user, you have to make sure the user has the appropriate access to the custom object. Unauthenticated users use the site's guest user profile to access custom objects. Remember to modify FLS as well if you have any custom fields. See the [Data Repeater](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_repeater.htm&language=en_US) and [Guest User Profile](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_access_perms.htm&language=en_US) help sections for more info.

Preview is using your currently logged in user which is why it works differently.